# How do I create an executable to install a dll and put a file in a certain folder?

Tags: python, c#, dll, installation, exe

I have a custom script coded in C# that is used in third-party software. 
I know the file directory my script needs to go into, but on each machine it could be different.

What will not change is the three folders the third-party software creates:

```
Acme Software\Add-on\Custom Script
```

The install directory is obviously a different question could be in volume C:, D: E:, etc. not to mention it could exist in its x86 program variant.

I know this could be achieved, and I know this isn't a specific code question.

How would I go about achieving this? What language, python? How would I create the .exe? If it's a dll I want to install how do I go about registering it? How do I make my files go into that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an installer.  Take a look at [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/).